# SQL: NOT IN, different field for same subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a subquery I need to check for two different columns, i.e. IT.Item_strItemId and IP.ItemItem_strItemId shall not be in the result of the subquery:

```
SELECT IT.Item_strItemId,
    IT.Item_strItemDescription
FROM tblItem IT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VISTAHO.dbo.tblItemPackage IP
        ON IT.Item_strItemId = IP.Item_strSubItemId
WHERE IT.Item_strItemId NOT IN (
        SELECT TI.Item_strItemId
        FROM VISTAHO.dbo.tblTrans_Inventory_HO TI
        GROUP BY TI.Item_strItemId
        HAVING DATEDIFF( MM , MAX(TI.TransI_dtmDateTime) , GetDate() ) <= 6
    ) AND IP.Item_strItemId NOT IN (
        SELECT TI.Item_strItemId
        FROM VISTAHO.dbo.tblTrans_Inventory_HO TI
        GROUP BY TI.Item_strItemId
        HAVING DATEDIFF( MM , MAX(TI.TransI_dtmDateTime) , GetDate() ) <= 6
    )
```

Is there a way to execute this without calling the subquery twice and without creating a table?

Comment: Have you tried a cte

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` is implicitly converted to an `INNER JOIN` here. `NULL` cannot be `NOT IN` anything. Is that intentional?

Comment: Great hint, I'll have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: What is the aim of the exercise? It is by no means certain that combining the predicate on both columns in to the sub query will improve performance compared to keeping them separate

Comment: @Lamu This is not intentional, Not all Items are Subitems of a Package. But those who are need not be in 'TI'

Comment: @MartinSmith Provide a list to Mgmt of items that have not been sold for some time for them to decide what is no longer needed.

Comment: No - what are you trying to get out of this refactoring? Just avoid having the same query text more than once or some supposed performance benefit?

Comment: @MartinSmith Get a better performance, 'tblTrans_Inventory_HO' has a lot of rows and querying through it is time consuming. Then, what is next time, when there is a bigger subquery and I don't have it to compare to two columns but to more. So, it's not only about query performance but _writting the query_ performance.

Comment: If you are just concerned about DRY then you can chuck the definition in a CTE and reference that twice. If you want to ensure that it is only evaluated once then this requires some examination of execution plans for potential rewrites. e.g. if it ends up on the inside of a nested loops then it will still be at least partially executed multiple times even if only appearing in the query text once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anti-join is a common pattern:

```
SELECT it.item_stritemid
     , it.item_stritemdescription
  FROM tblItem it
  LEFT
  JOIN VISTAHO.dbo.tblItemPackage ip
    ON it.item_stritemid = ip.item_strsubitemid

  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ti.item_stritemid
           FROM VISTAHO.dbo.tblTrans_Inventory_HO ti
          WHERE ti.item_stritemid IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY ti.item_stritemid
         HAVING DATEDIFF( MM , MAX(ti.transi_dtmdatetime) , GetDate() ) <= 6
       ) t
    ON t.item_stritemid = it.item_stritemid
    OR t.item_stritemid = ip.item_stritemid
 WHERE t.item_stritemid IS NULL
```

The subquery is used as an inline view; its a rowsource for an outer join operation. We're returning all rows along with matching rows from the subquery. The trick is the condition in the WHERE clause, requiring a NULL value in an expression we know won't be NULL if a matching row was found; we're eliminating all the rows that had a match, so we are returning only rows that don't have a match.

NOTE : The return from this query is not strictly equivalent to the original query

The original query is effectively and inner join to `ip`. With the outer join, if there isn't matching row in `ip`, the value of `ip.item_stritemid` will be NULL, and that will never satisfy a `NOT IN` condition. To make the query in this answer equivalent, we would need to remove the `LEFT` keyword.

Another corner case... we don't see a guarantee that `ti.item_stritemid` is always non-NULL. In the original query, the behavior of the `NOT IN (subquery)` when the subquery returns a NULL value (condition won't evaluate to TRUE) differs from the behavior of the query in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, there is not much you can do with `NOT IN`.  Even if you use a CTE, SQL Server will repeat calculation subquery twice.

Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`, checking for nothing in `tblTrans_Inventory_HO` in the past six *calendar* months:

```
SELECT IT.Item_strItemId, IT.Item_strItemDescription
FROM tblItem IT JOIN
     VISTAHO.dbo.tblItemPackage IP
     ON IT.Item_strItemId = IP.Item_strSubItemId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TI.Item_strItemId
                  FROM VISTAHO.dbo.tblTrans_Inventory_HO TI
                  WHERE TI.Item_strItemId = IT.Item_strItemId AND
                        DATEDIFF(MON, TI.TransI_dtmDateTime , GetDate() ) < 6
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT TI.Item_strItemId
                  FROM VISTAHO.dbo.tblTrans_Inventory_HO TI
                  WHERE TI.Item_strItemId = IP.Item_strItemId AND
                        DATEDIFF(MON, TI.TransI_dtmDateTime , GetDate() ) < 6
                 );
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `tblTrans_Inventory_HO(Item_strItemId, TransI_dtmDateTime)`.

The subqueries are actually better written like this, though:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TI.Item_strItemId
                  FROM VISTAHO.dbo.tblTrans_Inventory_HO TI
                  WHERE TI.Item_strItemId = IT.Item_strItemId AND
                        TI.TransI_dtmDateTime >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())), 1)
                 )
```

The date expression looks more complicated, but the complicated part can all be pre-calculated prior to execution.  That allows the optimizer to make even better use of the above index.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're actually after, but i am reading through the lines a little:

```
SELECT IT.Item_strItemId,
       IT.Item_strItemDescription
FROM dbo.tblItem IT
     INNER JOIN VISTAHO.dbo.tblItemPackage IP ON IT.Item_strItemId = IP.Item_strSubItemId --Assumed INNER JOIN is wanted, as it it an INNER JOIN in the OP
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM VISTAHO.dbo.tblTrans_Inventory_HO TI
                 WHERE TI.Item_strItemId IN (IT.Item_strItemId,IP.Item_strItemId)
                 GROUP BY TI.Item_strItemId
                 HAVING DATEDIFF( MM , MAX(TI.TransI_dtmDateTime) , GetDate() ) <= 6);
```